# What does "Archive does not contain 'android-something.txt'" mean?

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, rom-flashing, fastboot

So I am trying to flash my OnePlus One with CM12s through fastboot on command prompt, but whenever I type `fastboot update romname.zip` I am presented with:

```
archive does not contain 'android-info.txt'
archive does not contain 'android-product.txt'
error: update package has no android-info.txt or android-product.txt
```

the specific build I am using can be found [here](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=bacon&type=nightly) It is the build ending in 8, or the one submitted on 2015-07-08

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I never flashed a ROM using a `.zip` in fastboot. The proper way I've ever seen is to flash individual files, and some of the important commands are:

```
fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot flash cache cache.img
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot flash system system.img
fastboot flash userdata userdata.img // 64GB users need userdata_64G.img
```

Provided that you do have these individual files in your `.zip`.

These kind of zips are called as "fastboot zips" or "fastboot images", while those requiring a custom Recovery (as [keepclam mentioned](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/114768/96277)) are plainly known as normal recovery-flashable zips.

I'm not aware of custom ROMs providing "fastboot zips", but if you intend to gain an experience of flashing such zips, I would suggest flashing a stock CM12s. You can find the related info on OnePlus Forums [here](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/mirrors-for-official-cyanogen-roms-ota-updates.141825/).

About the error, it says you don't have `android-info.txt`. That's true that you probably don't have it because as I said custom ROMs usually don't provide "fastboot zips" which has this file. And I also said to try stock CM12s fastboot zip since it has that `android-info.txt` whose content would be like:

```
require version-trustzone=TZ.BF.2.0-2.0.0109
```

I think things would be clear for now.

Comment: None of these **.img**'s exist for pixel phones at this point.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I have not flashed a phone using fastboot images in the last two years so I'm afraid I cannot update my answer. Please do post an answer if you have one; downvote mine if you think that would be just; or raise a bounty to seek an updated answer. :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138084/discussion-on-answer-by-firelord-what-does-archive-does-not-contain-android-so).

Answer (score 1):

You need to flash custom ROMs from within recovery, not within the bootloader. Detailed instrunctions on how to install CyanogenMod can be found [here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_bacon).

NOTE: those instructions are not for the Cyanogen, Inc. factory images. Offical factory images can be found [on the Cyanogen, Inc. website](https://cyngn.com/support)